# jQuery calculate widths and change siblings on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

## The Goal

I want all my list items running horizontally across the page width the total width of all the li equaling 100%. I then want there to be one active li which is equal to 45% and for the script to calculate what the other li's width would compute once the active is triggered in order to keep the total to within the 100% limit to keep them all running horizontal.

I have some code that I'm trying to work it out with.

#### So far...

My code — as you will see — will change the width of the hovered element and adjust the children. However it only adjusts the children on `hoverout`. I can't quite work out how to make this work cleanly. I feel my approach is messy...

Help appreciated. See below for code and working example.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="tours">
    <ul class="tours-List">
        <li>
            <h2>Tour Item</h2>
            <a href="#">View more</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Tour Item</h2>
            <a href="#">View more</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Tour Item</h2>
            <a href="#">View more</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Tour Item</h2>
            <a href="#">View more</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Tour Item</h2>
            <a href="#">View more</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Tour Item</h2>
            <a href="#">View more</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Tour Item</h2>
            <a href="#">View more</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var
$li = $('.tours li'),
$is_active = false;

function checkActive() {
    if (!$li.hasClass("is-Active")) {
        $li.css({
            "width": 100 / $li.length + "%"
        });
    } else{
        $li.css('width', 58 / ($li.length -1) + "%");
    }
}

$li.css({
    "float": "left",
    "width": 100 / $li.length + "%"
});

$li.hover(function(e){
        $is_active = true;
        $(this).addClass("is-Active");
        $(this).css('width', '42%');
        
}, function(){
        $is_active = false;
        $(this).removeClass("is-Active");
        checkActive();
});
```

## [Live example](http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/KzoeWw)

Comment: Ok, I'm working on a answer. There are a lot of non-needed things in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, here is the js, simplified.

```
var $li = $('.tours li');
var widthPercentLeftWhenOneIsActive = 100-40; // you should use constant of course...

init();

function init(){
    $li.css({
        "float": "left",
        "width": 100 / $li.length + "%"
    });
};

$li.hover(function(e){
        $(this).css("width","");//remove inline style
        $(this).addClass("is-Active");
        //$(this).css('width', '42%'); move it to the css
        shrinkNonActiveItems();
}, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("is-Active");
        unShrinkAll();
});

function shrinkNonActiveItems(){
    $li.each(function(index, item){
        if(! $(item).hasClass("is-Active")){
            $(item).css("width", (widthPercentLeftWhenOneIsActive /     ($li.length-1))+"%" );
        }
    });
};

function unShrinkAll(){
    $li.each(function(index, item){
        $(item).css("width",100 / $li.length + "%");
    });    };
```

And a little bit of css

```
li.is-Active{
        width:40%;
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Just a technical querstion if I may.. Is it not bad practise to need to use `!important` in order to make this solution work fully?

Comment: Yes it is, you are right. You can get rid of it by adding a simple line in the JS part. `$li.hover(function(e){
   $(this).css("width","");
  $(this).addClass("is-Active"); ......` It is made to errase the inline style added by the `unShrinkAll()` function

Answer (score 0):

So, I have updated your code so it is working now. Please have a look at this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdqoaG

```js
var
 $li = $('.tours li'),
 $is_active = false;

function checkActive() {
 if (!$li.hasClass("is-Active")) {
  $li.css({
   "width": 100 / $li.length + "%"
  });
 } else {
  $li.each(function() {
   if(!$(this).hasClass("is-Active")){
    $(this).css('width', 58 / ($li.length -1) + "%");
   }
  })  
 }
}

$li.css({
 "float": "left",
 "width": 100 / $li.length + "%"
});

$li.hover(function(e) {
 $is_active = true;
 $(this).addClass("is-Active");
 $(this).css('width', '42%');
checkActive();
}, function() {
 $is_active = false;
 $(this).removeClass("is-Active");
 checkActive();
});
```

```css
.tours{
 
 &-List{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  li{
   list-style: none;
   background: {
    color: grey;
   }
   padding: 10em 2em 2em;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   
   @for $i from 1 through 7 {
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
     background-color: lighten(grey, $i * 3);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tours">
 <ul class="tours-List">
  <li>
   <h2>Tour Item</h2>
   <a href="#">View more</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <h2>Tour Item</h2>
   <a href="#">View more</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <h2>Tour Item</h2>
   <a href="#">View more</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <h2>Tour Item</h2>
   <a href="#">View more</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <h2>Tour Item</h2>
   <a href="#">View more</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <h2>Tour Item</h2>
   <a href="#">View more</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <h2>Tour Item</h2>
   <a href="#">View more</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code after you are assigning `42% width` on the hovered item.

It's because - first all the items are getting identical width - then when you are increasing size of one - the rest remains as originals.

```
$li.each(function(){
            if (!$(this).hasClass("is-Active")) {
                $(this).css({
                    "width": 58 / 6 + "%"
                });
            }
        });
```

you can replace `hard-coded` **6** by `$li.length` minus one.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not answer the question, are you aware that you can achieve this with css?

http://jsfiddle.net/4watyjyp/

```
ul {
  display: table;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
}
li:hover {
  width: 45%;
}
```